# Perforce Archive Contents

Tags: perforce

I want to list the directories in a perforce archive on a separate drive /otherdrive/myarchive. I can archive and restore files but p4 dirs //myarchive/depot/* gives the error

```
//myarchive/depot/*/... - must refer to client 'SERVER_NAME'.
```

when i try p4 dirs /otherdrive/myarchive/depot/* i get

```
Path '/otherdrive/myarchive/depot/*/...' is not under client's root '/home/USER'.
```

My skill level is an artist that knows some linux commands, not a sysadmin or perforce expert, so please tell me if I have left out important info necessary to answer the question.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you run commands against the Perforce server, what you're querying is the Perforce database, which is the source of truth for what's "in Perforce".  Depot specifications (created with `p4 depot` and listed by `p4 depots`) are the root of Perforce's file namespace, and they associate that namespace with the archives on the actual disk (via the `Map` field).

So if you have a depot called `depot`, you can see the top level directories in that depot (again, in Perforce's database, which isn't necessarily the same as what's on disk) by doing:

```
p4 dirs //depot/*
```

But if you want to see what's *on disk* in the depot archive, you need to go completely outside of Perforce and run a command like:

```
ls -l /otherdrive/myarchive/depot
```

As an end user, you almost *never* want to (or should even be allowed to) do something like the latter.

As an admin you should generally only be concerned with the archive files insofar as it's necessary to make sure they're safely backed up; Perforce manages the archive files and their relationships with the database, and if you start messing around with them you're likely to break those relationships in ways that will mess up your actual Perforce usage later.

Comment: Thanks Samwise, that makes it clear. The reason I want to know what's in the archive is so I can keep an up to date list of which folders are archived or not so everyone who can't log in to the server has an overview. I won't be making any changes without using p4 archive and p4 restore.

Comment: If you want to keep track of what you archived into an archive depot, what you might want is `p4 restore -D myarchive -n //...`?